# Can someone help me using 'ray' or other multiprocessing libraries for my semantic segmentation?

Tags: python, multithreading, image-processing, multiprocessing, ray

I'm doing semantic segmentation for microscope image stacks.
My code works fine but the thing is it only uses one core of my CPU which makes me wait a long time to get the segmented images.

I recently knew that there are ways to use multicore processing with other python libraries, but I don't know how to implement it.

So someone can help me edit my code with one of the multiprocessing libraries?
My code is in the below.

```
import numpy as np
from patchify import patchify, unpatchify
import os
import cv2
from tqdm import tqdm
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.utils import normalize
import natsort

model = keras.models.load_model("C:/mymodel.h5", compile=False)

  

#creating recon image directory
recon_image_directory = "C:/Users/recon"
if not os.path.exists(recon_image_directory):
    os.makedirs(recon_image_directory)


large_image_path = "C:/original_images/" 
check_images = natsort.natsorted(os.listdir(large_image_path)) 

for num, large_image_name in tqdm(enumerate(check_images), total=len(check_images)):
    if (large_image_name.split('.')[1] == "tif"):
        img = cv2.imread(large_image_path + large_image_name, 0)
        patches = patchify(img, (256, 256), step=256)
        
        predicted_patches = []
        for i in range(patches.shape[0]):
            for j in range(patches.shape[1]):
                
                single_patch = patches[i,j,:,:] #(256, 256)
                single_patch_norm = normalize(np.array(single_patch), axis=1) 
                single_patch_input = np.stack((single_patch_norm,)*3, axis=-1) # (256, 256, 3) 
                single_patch_input = np.expand_dims(single_patch_input, 0) #(1,256,256,3)
                
                single_patch_prediction = (model.predict(single_patch_input)[0,:,:,0]>0.5).astype(np.uint8) 
               
                predicted_patches.append(single_patch_prediction)
                
        predicted_patches = np.array(predicted_patches)
        predicted_patches_reshaped = np.reshape(predicted_patches, (patches.shape[0], patches.shape[1], 256,256) )
        reconstructed_image = unpatchify(predicted_patches_reshaped, img.shape)
        
        cv2.imwrite(recon_image_directory + "/recon"+'_' + str(num) +  ".tif", reconstructed_image)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this snippet work? It should run each prediction in a separate process.

```
@ray.remote
def predict(large_image_name: str) -> None:
    img = cv2.imread(large_image_path + large_image_name, 0)
    patches = patchify(img, (256, 256), step=256)
    
    predicted_patches = []
    for i in range(patches.shape[0]):
        for j in range(patches.shape[1]):
            
            single_patch = patches[i,j,:,:] #(256, 256)
            single_patch_norm = normalize(np.array(single_patch), axis=1) 
            single_patch_input = np.stack((single_patch_norm,)*3, axis=-1) # (256, 256, 3) 
            single_patch_input = np.expand_dims(single_patch_input, 0) #(1,256,256,3)
            
            single_patch_prediction = (model.predict(single_patch_input)[0,:,:,0]>0.5).astype(np.uint8) 
            
            predicted_patches.append(single_patch_prediction)
            
    predicted_patches = np.array(predicted_patches)
    predicted_patches_reshaped = np.reshape(predicted_patches, (patches.shape[0], patches.shape[1], 256,256) )
    reconstructed_image = unpatchify(predicted_patches_reshaped, img.shape)
    
    cv2.imwrite(recon_image_directory + "/recon"+'_' + str(num) +  ".tif", reconstructed_image)
    
futures = []
for num, large_image_name in tqdm(enumerate(check_images), total=len(check_images)):
    if (large_image_name.split('.')[1] == "tif"):
        futures.append(predict.remote(large_image_name))

ray.get(futures)
```

We also have a high-level abstraction for doing this sort of thing. If you're interested, you should check out the [Ray AI Runtime (AIR)](https://docs.ray.io/en/master/ray-air/getting-started.html).

Comment: Thanks for your help! I got the error.
RuntimeError: The remote function failed to import on the worker. This may be because needed library dependencies are not installed in the worker environment:

Comment: Ah, yeah. If you haven't seen it already, the [Environment Dependencies user guide](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/ray-core/handling-dependencies.html) might be useful.